# How do you add a single quote for javascript in an Html.TextBoxFor method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am attempting to add a javascript method as a custom attribute in an Html.TextBoxFor method like this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateCreated, new { size="15", onfocus="myObject.myFunction(this, 'DateCreated');return false;"}) %>
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that the single quote characters are being html encoded, which is an expection I have of the `<%:`. Is there a way to prevent the html encoding for just that piece (like using a \ to escape characters in strings)? Is there a different method of adding this custom attribute? Or am I just flat out doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the quotes are being encoded your javascript should work. For example the following snippet alerts the correct text:

```
<%: Html.TextBox("DateCreated", "", new { onclick="alert('DateCreated');return false;"}) %>
```

Another way to achieve this is to use unobtrusive javascript and not mix markup with script:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateCreated, new { size="15", id="date" }) %>
```

and then in a separate javascript file using jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#date').focus(function() {
        myObject.myFunction(this, 'DateCreated');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I will give the alert a try just to make sure that I'm reading the actual problem and not just what I want to see as a problem. I'll need to make any jquery method such as that a little more generic if I'm to use it, only because I have a lot of items such as this one and throwing one in for each is going to get heavy.

Comment: I found that by simply declaring the string as a javascript variable, I could pass the variable name in without issue. Maybe in the future I can make that jquery method generic to be used with any control without hard-coding a name in, but for now it appears that the addition of the single quote is not causing any of my problems. I will have to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The default encoder in .NET 4 encodes characters it deems to be potentially unsafe, including ', ", &, <, and >.  However, this encoding should not affect the execution of the Javascript snippet you're trying to include, since the browser will automatically turn the &#39; back into the ' character before passing it to the Javascript parser.  If this is still negatively affecting your application, please respond so that we can consider getting an official bug filed.

If you want, you can change the default encoder used by ASP.NET to one of your own creation.  Phil outlined at http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx the steps needed to hook up the Anti-XSS encoder.  But if you wanted, you could make a custom HttpEncoder that encoded everything *except* the ' character by following the same basic steps.

Comment: I'm going to try @Darin Dimitrov's alert suggestion just to make sure that it is in fact the culprit causing my problem.